# Returns Pair of two elements - Homework problem Google Challenge

Tags: c, algorithm, testing, architecture, software-design

I'm struggling to implement in C a function that gets as two inputs , one input is an integer array, second input is the given sum.

the function returns the pairs of two element that its sum equal to the given sum.

I don't have much experience in C , and I started to implement the function by myself.

I've seen the solution here step by step :
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJP62MCWTM8)

but I really didn't understand the logic of the explained code in the video, could anyone please explain to me the algorithm / the code that's explained on the video?

how really we find the matched two pairs that its sum equal to the given sum?

For me a pseudo code is also awesome to understand the solution of the problem.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

@RyanRonad, the explanation is quite clear in the video so I'm not sure where you got question. This is the famous `Two Sum` problem for interview.  Let's go step-by-step here to explain the logic

1. The key to the problem is that there is ALWAYS only 1 pair of numbers that satisfy the condition of adding together to be the target value. (x1 + x2 == `Sum` target)
   We can assume that for all the numbers in the list (x1, x2, ... xn) that there exists a pair such that a + b == target is True!
2. To solve this with a single pass of the list we can change the equation above to a = target - b and since we know the target as long as we maintain a record of all previous values in the list we can compare the current value (a) to it's ONLY pair, if it exists, in record of all previous values (b)
3. To keep a record of the previous values and their indices we can use a dictionary/hashmap (commonly known as a map in other languages). This allows us to record each previous number in the dictionary alongside the indices as a key value pair (target-number, indices).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't opened the link but I want to give you a simple way:

For each element of the array check if summing it with each of the following elements gives you the target value.

The code would be a double `for` loop:

```
int len = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); // number of elements of arr[]
int *pair = malloc( sizeof(int) * 2 ); // array used to return the pair

for(int i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {

    for(int j = i+1: j < len; j++) {

        if( arr[i] + arr[j] == sum ) {

            pair[0] = i;
            pair[1] = j;
            goto: thats_it;
        }
    }
}

thats_it:

return pair;
```

Where `arr[]` and `sum` are those they give you.

If you don't like to use `goto` you can do

```
i = len;
break;
```

Where `break;` breaks the inner loop and `i = len;` breaks the outer one.

Or you could just put the `return` inside the `if`, but I really don't like to do that. I like to always have only one clear exit point at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each element in the list. For each element, loop through the list and check if the exits another element,in the list, that when added to the current element will equal to the desired sum. You'll effectively have two for loops.

Have a look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void    *pair_sum(int *A,int sum){
    int len = 6;
    int i,j;
    static int final[2];

    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++){
            for (j = 0; j <= len; i++){
                    if (A[i]+A[j] == sum){
                            final[0]=A[i];
                            final[1] = A[j];
                            return(final);
                    }       
            }
    }
    

}

int     main(){
    int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int sum = 10;
    int i,j;
    int *root;

    root = pair_sum(A,sum);
    printf("%d %d",*(root),*(root+1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `len` is the length of the array, then `i <= len` cause you to access the array out of bounds. And starting the inner loop from `0` is inefficient, but more importantly will make you do the sum of an element by itself when `i` and `j` get the same value.

Comment: Thanks, that should be `i <= len - 1` or simply '`i < len` ... As to your second point, I left it starting from zero for clarity, of course for efficiency you'd let the inner loop start at `j = i + 1`

Comment: But if you leave it from 0, then you need to add a condition to avoid elements summing to themselves: `if (A[i]+A[j] == sum && i != j)`